# Split sentence into words and check MySQL for occurance

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a variable that is a sentence for example `this is a sentence`. I have a MySQL database which has rows where one column contains the following:

```
"random sentences" 
"few random words" 
"this is cool"
"a car" 
"nice placement"
```

I need to print out occurrences of any word in the sentence existing in the database rows. For the example sentence given above, the result would be:

```
"random sentences" 
"this is cool" 
"a car"
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "dsfdsfds";
$password = "sdfdfsdsf";
$dbname = "sdf";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$galleries = "This is a sentence";
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM rawwords 
 WHERE origin LIKE '%" . $galleries. "%'
";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - location: " . $row["sentence"]. " <br><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `$galleries` is a sentence, not a group of words. `explode` on spaces, or `preg_split` on spaces and punctuation, and then build the `where` dynamically for each word. Also parameterize your query.

Comment: Just for clarity, based on your examples, when $galleries="This is a sentance", what would you want the expected output to be?

Answer (score 0):

Create the right sql :D

```
$galleries ="This is a sentence";
$arr = explode(" ", $galleries);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM rawwords WHERE origin LIKE";

$lenght = count($arr);

for ($i=0; $i<$lenght; $i++) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        $sql .=" '% " . $arr[$i]. " %'";
    } else {
        $sql .=" or '% " . $arr[$i]. " %'";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `REGEXP` to fin words in your sentences using `[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]` (word boundaries). You could split your string to get words, then use `array_map()` to transform them for the query. Finally, you could use `implode()` with `" or "` glue:

```
$galleries = "This is a sentence" ;
$words = preg_split('~\W~', $galleries, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$words = array_map(function($word) { 
    return ' origin REGEXP "[[:<:]]'.$word.'[[:>:]]" '; 
}, $words);
$where = implode(' OR ', $words);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM rawwords WHERE $where";
```

Will generate the query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM rawwords 
WHERE origin REGEXP "[[:<:]]This[[:>:]]" 
   OR origin REGEXP "[[:<:]]is[[:>:]]" 
   OR origin REGEXP "[[:<:]]a[[:>:]]" 
   OR origin REGEXP "[[:<:]]sentence[[:>:]]"
```

---

**Important**, you should have an attentive look to parameterized queries.
Please read this article with several examples: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)